# How can I grep for the Trademark Symbol ™?

Tags: grep

How I can generate a list of files that contain the trademark symbol (™ ALT+0153)?

I believe this may be possible by using perl regular expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
echo "How I can generate a list of files that contain the trademark symbol (™ ALT+0153)?" | \
    grep -P "\x6b"
```

Output:

```
How I can generate a list of files that contain the trademark symbol (™ ALT+0153)?
```

So the general command is

```
grep -I -l -r -P "\x6b" *
```

- **0153 (oct) == 6B (hex)**